# Java XML binding with nested generic tags

Tags: java, xml, binding

I need an efficient way to convert XML to *meaningful* domain objects in Java. Below is a selection of XML that I have to work with (some values have been obscured). Here are the basic constraints I have to work with:

1. There is no schema to work with. Auto-generated schemas don't turn out well because of the variable "nesting."
2. Any given domain-object can contain 0-* domain-object tags
3. Any given domain-object can contain 0-* value tags.
4. Not all nesting is created equal. In some cases, the "key" of a value includes implicit nesting. For example, "config[0].cbs" indicates a collection of config objects, each with a different value for .cbs
5. Changing the XML structure may not be possible.
6. The "represents" attribute indicates a type.
7. The "nestedKey" attribute indicates a variable name inside a type.
8. These XML files can be quite large.

I've tried using JAXB, but things aren't working out because of the "generic-ness" of the tags. Perhaps my JAXB-fu is insufficient. The current implementation (I inherited this) is SAX, but it doesn't actually work. I've looked at XStream, but it seems to assume some semantic structure to the tags.

I would like a least-code, most-flexible, most-extendable approach to generate *meaningful* domain objects. I'd like to avoid nesting HashMaps if possible (that's part of the current solution that doesn't work). Creative, hack-y, or clever ideas are welcome as well as striaght-forward "duh" answers too.

XML Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<domain-objects>
    <types language="C++">
        <type prefix="bool" language-representation="bool" />
        <type prefix="char" language-representation="char" />
        <type prefix="domain_object" language-representation="opti::DomainObject" />
        <type prefix="domain_object" language-representation="DomainObject" />
        <type prefix="double" language-representation="double" />
        <type prefix="float" language-representation="float" />
...
    </types>
    <domain-object key="(unique object id)" represents="PerfSuite">
        <domain-object key="(unique object id)" nestedKey="testCore" represents="PerfTestCore">
            <value key="suiteUuid" type="stl_string">(unique object id)</value>
            <value key="suiteName" type="stl_string">(some name)</value>
            <value key="suiteId" type="int">(some number)</value>
            <value key="suiteDeleted" type="bool">false</value>
        </domain-object>
        <domain-object key="(unique object id)" nestedKey="testResults" represents="PerfTestResults">
            <domain-object key="(unique object id)" nestedKey="services_0" represents="PerfServiceResult">
                <domain-object key="(unique object id)" nestedKey="stepResults_0" represents="PerfStepResult">
                    <value key="ir.max" type="int64">(some number)</value>
                    <value key="ftd.avg" type="float">(some number)</value>
                    <value key="ftd.max" type="float">(some number)</value>
...
                </domain-object>
                <value key="duration" type="uint">(some number)</value>
                <value key="flow" type="uint16">(some number)</value>
...
                        <value key="config[1].flrThreshold" type="float">(some number)</value>
                        <value key="config[1].fdvPercent" type="float">(some number)</value>
                        <value key="index" type="uint16">(some number)</value>
                        <value key="config[0].cbs" type="uint64">(some number)</value>
                        <value key="svlanVid" type="uint16">(some number)</value>
                        <value key="config[1].availThreshold" type="float">(some number)</value>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

No one tool will solve this problem for you entirely.

JAXB might still be the right answer for the parsing part.  You will have to do the final pass yourself if you are looking to have each of the domain objects translated into your actual domain objects.

JAXB wont be able to parse out "float" to determine that it needs to lookup the types table to find that float maps to float.  Finding "config[1].fdvPercent" in your object is also beyond its capabilities.

From what I can see, you have a fairly consistent document structure that could be described by a schema.  Writing this in XML schema, or annotating classes should be straightforward.

```
domain-objects = types+, domain-object+
domain-object = domain-object*, value*
```

From here, you have your work cut out for you.  I suspect that you will need a number of things:

- per-type parsing of the strings in each element so you can get the value for each
- a mapping from the string value of types to the per-type parsers (it looks like you might need an extra mapping step to go from the C++? types you use to the Java type)
- a parser for the value keys so that you can find the variable to apply the value to
- some reflection to instantiate objects and set the value in the created object

I can't guess what nestedKey or represents means to you.  Those might require additional steps.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you are saying I will need to: 1) convert from XML to generic domain objects and then 2) convert from generic to *meaningful* domain objects. Correct?

Comment: That is the gist of it.  If you don't consider a generic "value" object to be useful, then you need to some of your own conversion.  No tool exists to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Martin, thanks for your answer. This is pretty much the conclusion that I've come to and I'm hoping against hope that there is another/better way. I realize that there is no one "tool" that will do this, but I'm hoping there is a clever-er approach to tackling this problem.